# Hierarchial Forecasting in R using HTS - Error in "characters="

Tags: r, forecasting, hierarchical

Rob J Hyndman and Earo Wang,
Thank you for all the work on forecasting, especially the hts package.  For the life of me, I can't figure out how to get the characters working in the hts package.

The string, which contains 29 characters, always has the following format:

```
X123412341234123412_AA_789789
```

Of which. there are three hierarchies:

```
X123412341234123412
_AA_
789789
```

I have tried the following characters:

```
characters=list(c(19,4,6))
characters=list(c(29))
characters=list(c(19,10))
```

I always receive the following errors:

```
Error in sum(characters) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument
```

How would you set up the "characters="

Thank you for your time,
Philip

Comment: `characters=c(19,4,6)`

Comment: Rob, Thank You!